# The circle with minimal radius covering known finite set of points on a plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

Given some points on a plane, how to determine the circle with minimal radius covering all these points?

Comment: It can be solved in linear time via Linear Programming: Megiddo, Nimrod (1983), "Linear-time algorithms for linear programming in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and related problems", *SIAM Journal on Computing* 12 (4): 759–776.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I quoted Meggido's 32-yr-old LP algorithm in the comments,
a simpler-to-implement randomized algorithm has expected linear time and space complexity,
and is the most common implementation,
e.g., as cited below the figure.

---

[image: EnclosingCirc]

          

<sup>(Image from [code.project.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22568/Computational-Geometry-C-and-Wykobi).)</sup>

---

A clear description of this algorithm may be found in this
lecture prepared by Marc van Kreveld and Maarten Loffler: [PDF slides download](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides4b.pdf).

CGAL implements both a heuristic algorithm,
and the LP algorithm, in $\mathbb{R}^d$: [CGAL implementation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Bounding_volumes/classCGAL_1_1Min__sphere__of__spheres__d.html).